# Herdar módulos e variáveis de inicialização em um script Python para outro script Python com Gtk3

Tags: python, gtk-python

Boa Noite!
Estou trabalhando com Gtk3 e Python3 e estou estruturando meu projeto para construção de um ERP para plataforma GNU/LINUX. Estou utilizando o Glade para construção da interface gráfica e utilizando o Builder do Gtk para manipular os componentes da interface gráfica. No exemplo abaixo eu pretendi exemplificar minha ideia de forma bem genérica com dois aquivos .py um para cada janela, pois os quero estruturar o meu projeto em módulos separados aonde eu possa chamar um de cada vez para não sobrecarregar as máquinas aonde ele vai rodar, sempre levando em conta que eu preciso construir um sistema leve para maquinas que já estão ultrapassadas :(.

Arquivo 1 (Janela 1) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
import base64
import zlib
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

ui = Gtk.Builder()
ui.add_from_string(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(b'eJyNksFSwjAQhu88xbpXp0D14qGtM86IL6DjsbNNFhpZE0xSkEfyOXwxgxUBYdRbJvn23/33T3H9+iywZB+MsyXmwzECW+W0sbMSH+4n2RVeV4PiLMvgji17iqxhZWILMyHNcDm8uBjmkGUJMjayn5LiagBQeH7pjOcAYpoSZ3F+jrtGqWyMo0/ONU+sIiihEEq8i/NHY7VbIRhd4hNZFspxQyZ24d2CfVyDpWcuUZGtp051AasJSeBitAW++GBmluSL1hyid2uElqwW9iWSqwMZX/dd6hwhrGix4NTYun68JKJaI7o/b0aQZLB1otlvgdEe8YM+MnfTxehsb66J9aG/Ux6FGhaE6MkGoUiNpMs1J8u3IRK8vwFBrwL5T/+n9JYmmKSB1b3vjhb2x5L/W+JZsVlyqDVPqZP4S+VBQkqMmrPeS2hz47rvNZ3KZxNAv+ajOHYPxWjvc34Ayi/vWQ==')).decode("utf-8"))

class Janela1(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Handler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # --> Inicialização
        self.usuario = "TESTE" # --> Gostaria de herdar a variável de inicialização dessa janela1 para janela2
    
    # -- ao sair da janela1 destroy a aplicação
    def ao_sair_janela_1(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()
    
    # -- Ao clicar no botão da janela1 é impresso na saida padrão a
    # -- mensagem e posteriormente chamo a janela2
    def clicou_janela1(self, *args):
        print("Clicou janela 1")
        
        import janela2 as janela #--> Aqui importo o script da janela2 e apelido de "janela"
        janela.execucao(classe=janela.Janela2) #--> Chamo minha função na janela2 aonde ligo os sinais 
                                               #--> da janela e crio um loop do Gtk para segunda Janela
        
ui.connect_signals(Janela1())
window = ui.get_object("janela1")
window.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gtk.main()
```

Arquivo 2 (Janela 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
import os
import base64
import zlib
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
ui = Gtk.Builder()
# --> (Dúvida: da linha 4 a 10 não queria importar esses módulos novamente,
# --> gostaria de herdar eles da primeira janela)

# --> Arquivo da janela2 
def modulo(string=b'eJyNkk1SAjEQhfecou2tNfy5cTEDVVYJF8BySfUkDQSaBJMMyJE8hxczOFCgQ6G7VPK9/nkv+fB9LbBlH4yzBfbaXQS2ymlj5wW+TEbZIw4Hrfwuy2DMlj1F1rAzcQFzIc3w0O732z3IsgQZG9nPSPGgBZB7fquM5wBiygLncXWP50ZJ1sXON+fKJasISiiEAsdx9WqsdjsEowtckmWhPh7IxG6827CPe7C05gIV2enMqSrgYEQSOO+cgOv82mkSHEx81USDmVuSI6g5RO/2CAuyWtgXSG4ayPjpaSAIO9psOI1oXb1IqqEWRnR9PjSXZMXCiWZ/AjoXxC+6YcNTFaOztQ1lPDbu4UnQ3E6oZEGInmwQilRKutxzMuc5RILPDyCoq0D/9/rX6m1NMKnGdb/+iOO/Es+KzZbDVPOMKok3lD8CUmLUivVFQIcbV93M5xBAbXMjjvND3rn4xl9Nhv2k'):
    return string

# --> Conexão dos sinais e criação do Loop para janela
def execucao(classe=None):
    ui.connect_signals(classe())
    Gtk.main()
    
class Janela2(object):
    def __init__(self, interface=modulo(), *args, **kwargs):
        ui.add_from_string(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(interface)).decode("utf-8"))
        super(Janela2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # --> Inicialização
        self.janela2 = ui.get_object("janela2")
        self.janela2.show_all()
    
    # -- Fecha a janela2
    def ao_sair_janela2(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()
    
    # -- Exibe a mensagem quando clicado no botão da janela2
    def clicou_janela2(self, *args):
        print("Clicou na janela 2")
```

Minha dúvida é mesmo como herdar os os módulos já importados na janela1 para  janela2, assim como as variáveis de inicialização da janela1 para janela2

Se alguém puder me dar uma força agradeço!
Valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa Noite Pessoal!
Acredito ter chegado a um modelo funcional para resolução do meu problema, queria somente a orientações de vocês se estou no caminho certo.
As modificações que realizei foi que ao invés de utilizar o add_from_string do Gtk.Builder eu passei a utilizar o add_from_objects_string pois ele se aptou melhor ao meu modelo de estruturação do projeto. Também consertei o problema de ter que criar um novo loop do Gtk.main() para construção da segunda janela, agora como o amigo @jsbueno orientou eu faço chamadas somente do Gtk, e as propriedades que preciso herdar na segunda janela viraram parâmetros de classe da mesma. Abaixo segue os dois arquivos que realizei as modificações:

Arquivo 1 (Janela1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
import base64
import zlib
import sqlite3

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

ui = Gtk.Builder()
janela1 = (zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(b'eJyNksFSwjAQhu88xbpXp0D14qGtM86IL6DjsbNNFhpZE0xSkEfyOXwxgxUBYdRbJvn23/33T3H9+iywZB+MsyXmwzECW+W0sbMSH+4n2RVeV4PiLMvgji17iqxhZWILMyHNcDm8uBjmkGUJMjayn5LiagBQeH7pjOcAYpoSZ3F+jrtGqWyMo0/ONU+sIiihEEq8i/NHY7VbIRhd4hNZFspxQyZ24d2CfVyDpWcuUZGtp051AasJSeBitAW++GBmluSL1hyid2uElqwW9iWSqwMZX/dd6hwhrGix4NTYun68JKJaI7o/b0aQZLB1otlvgdEe8YM+MnfTxehsb66J9aG/Ux6FGhaE6MkGoUiNpMs1J8u3IRK8vwFBrwL5T/+n9JYmmKSB1b3vjhb2x5L/W+JZsVlyqDVPqZP4S+VBQkqMmrPeS2hz47rvNZ3KZxNAv+ajOHYPxWjvc34Ayi/vWQ==')).decode("utf-8"))
ui.add_objects_from_string(janela1, ["janela1"])

class Handler(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Handler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
    # --> Inicialização
        self.window = ui.get_object("janela1")
        self.window.show_all()
        
        self.conexao = sqlite3.connect("banco.db")
        self.cursor = self.conexao.cursor()
        
    def ao_sair_janela_1(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()
    
    # -- Sinal conectado a um GtkButton
    def clicou_janela1(self, *args):
        print("Clicou janela 1")
        from janela2 import Janela2
        Janela2(construtor=ui, conexao=self.conexao, cursor=self.cursor)
        
ui.connect_signals(Handler())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gtk.main()
```

Arquivo 2 (Janela2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
import base64
import zlib

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

janela2 = (zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(b'eJyNkk1uAjEMhfecwvW2Gv666WIGpEqFC1B1iTyJgYBJaJKBcqSeoxdr6ICgHUS7i5zvOfZ7yYfva4Et+2CcLbDX7iKwVU4bOy/wZTLKHnE4aOV3WQZjtuwpsoadiQuYC2mGh3a/3+5BliXI2Mh+RooHLYDc81tlPAcQUxY4j6t7PD+UZF3sfHOuXLKKoIRCKHAcV6/GardDMLrAJVkW6uOBTOzGuw37uAdLay5QkZ3OnKoCDkYkgfPOCbjOr50mwcHEV000mLklOYKahSNnvGUbERZktbAvkNw0kPHT01QQdrTZcJrTunqb1EgtjOj6fJhAkh8LJ5r9CehcEL/ohhdPVYzO1l6U8fhwD0+C5opCJQtC9GSDUKRSUnHPyaHnEAk+P4Cg7gL93x5c67c1waQe1037I5P/SjwrNlsOU80zqiTeUP5ISYlRK9YXAR0qrrqZzyGA2uZGHOeLvHPxl78AjX7/XA==')).decode("utf-8"))

class Janela2(object):
    def __init__(self, construtor, usuario=None, conexao=None, cursor=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Janela2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
    # --> Inicialização
        self.construtor = construtor
        self.construtor.add_objects_from_string(janela2, ["janela2"])
        self.construtor.connect_signals(self)
        self.conexao = conexao
        self.cursor = cursor
        
        self.cursor.execute(" create table if not exists login("
                            " usuario text not null,"
                            " senha text not null)")
        self.conexao.commit()
        self.window = self.construtor.get_object("janela2")
        self.window.show_all()
    
    
    # -- Sinal conectado a uma GtkWindow
    def ao_sair_janela2(self, *args):
        jn = self.window 
        jn.destroy()
        return True
    
    # -- Sinal conectado a um GtkButton
    def clicou_janela2(self, *args):
        print("Clicou na janela 2")
```

Na segunda janela eu até demostrei oque eu precisava herdar na verdade da primeira janela, e esta funcionando, agora se esta correto a ponto de se tornar um modelo para construção de vários módulos seguindo o mesmo molde não tenho certeza, precisava da ajuda de vocês.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Especificamente sobre a sua dúvida:

Se o seu programa tem varias vezes o mesmo import em arquivos .py diferentes,
o Python **não carrega  outras cópias do módulo importado**. Apenas o primeiro import traz o código para a memória. Outras importações de "zlib" ou "base64", pra falar desse exemplo, somente criam variáveis novas, no ponto onde está o comando de 'import', referenciando o mesmo objeto na memória.

Agora, alguns comentários sobre a sua arquitetura:

Ter o código para 1 ou 20 janelas em uma única aplicação Python não vai "aumentar o peso" do seu sistema  - não se preocupe com isso: o código usado pela pilha sistema Operacional, + ambietne gráfico + conectores de banco de dados + runtime do Python deve precisar de entre 600 e 800MB pra funcionar. Cada módulo do seu sistema, mesmo se for bastante complexo, vai usar de memória o equivalente ao que a descrição do módulo em código fonte usa  - ou seja, mesmo um arquivo muito complexo dificilmente vai passar dos 100KB de "peso" extra.

Você só consegue "gastar memória" de forma significativa se tentar, por exemplo, carregar o movimento de caixa de vários dias de operação em memória, e ficar operando com isso.

Resumo até aqui: você não precisa dividir sua aplicação por "questão de performance" - você pode dividir os módulos para se preocupar com manter o sistema organizado e mantível. Se isso for aumentar a complexidade, você está indo na contramão.

Agora-a forma como vocẽ optou por manter a interface gerada pelo glade
no seu sistema também não é prática: você tem essencialmente
código compilado dentro dos seus arquivos de código fonte -
o ideal é manter os arquivos XML em uma pasta, próximos dos seus arquivos .py
mesmo, e carregar de um arquivo.

O "ganho de performance" de ter a descrição da interface numa string
base-64 encode, zipada, embutida no seu código fonte é
negligível - isso se houver qualquer ganho,e é muito possível
que não. Por outro lado, você perde muito, mas muito mesmo, em
o quanto fica fácil manter o seu código: qualquer mudança na interface você
tem que usar o glade, gerar a string com a interface,e "colar" ela dentro
do seu código fonte do app. é muito mais simples se os arquivos que
o glade gera ficarem no sistema de arquivos direto -- você altera o que precisa
e seu arquivo .py continua funcionando sem precisar de nenhuma alteração.

Se você quer entregar um único arquivo para o usuário final, depois vendo sobre
empacotamento, você vai ver que pode criar um arquivo ".egg" ou ".wheel" que contém o seu código junto com os xml e pode ser usado de forma direta - embora
idealmente voĉe mnta as coisas de forma que em cada máquina é executado um "pip install"  do seu projeto - e isso já copia todos os arquivos necessários para sua execução na instalação de Python onde foi feito o comando "pip".

--
Ultima dica: você está chamando "gtk.main()" em mais de um ponto - isso não está certo - gtk.main deve ser chamado uma única vez na aplicação - você pode esconder uma janela e apresentar outra, com chamadas por dentro do gtk.

Comment: Boa Tarde jsbueno!

Comment: obrigado por responder acredito que estou no caminho certo então, estava com um pouco de receio de ficar importando módulos para cada janela e causar um problema de excesso de memória usada.

Comment: A respeito do gtk.main() irei restruturar o processo e qualquer dúvida volto a perguntar.

Comment: agora a respeito de variáveis de inicialização por exemplo quando eu chamar um novo módulo quero passar para ele algumas informações, exemplo o usuário que chamou este módulo entre outras coisas, quando estou trabalhando em um projeto que existe um único arquivo do Glade eu utilizo somente chamadas do Gtk para as janelas agora quando eu parti para uma estruturação separadas em módulos tive essa dúvida, e acabei montando essa gambiarra para funcionar em parte.

Comment: Não sei se existe algum conteúdo que aborde essa questão em especifico, utilizando Python ou C para que eu possa estudar.

Comment: você não pode passar variáveis paa "módulos'  -mas já que está definidno suas janela sem classes - sim, quando você cria uma classe, pode passar parâmetros, que viram parametros no métod 'init" - e esses parâmetros podem ser controles gtk na primeira janela, onde métodos da segunda janela podem ler os valores, por exemplo  - não precisam ser valores congelados.